# File write with Encoding in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, file-io, character-encoding, c++builder

My Environment: RadStudio XE4 Update1 on Windows7 pro (32bit).

When we want to write file with Encoding, what are the APIs?

I found `TStreamWriter.Create(FileName, ..., TEncoding.GetEncoding(...))` as one option.
Is this what are used normally?

I also found `TStringList.SaveToFile()` with Encoding.

I tried to find the way to specify Encoding for `FileOpen()`/`Filewrite()`, but did not find the related information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [AssignFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.AssignFile) function. From XE it has an optional `CodePage` parameter that sets the codepage of the output file (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14243866/3235496).

Also the [TStringStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TStringStream)::[Create](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TStringStream.Create) method accepts a `TEncoding` parameter.
While `TStringList` is line-oriented, the `TStringStream` class is very useful to read/write string blob (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6397914/3235496).

These should cover many typical use cases.

`FileOpen()` / `FileWrite()` are lower-level file access routines. Embarcadero doesn't encourage the use of the non-native Delphi language file handlers and for normal file operations they suggest `AssignFile`, `Rewrite` and `Reset` instead.

EDIT

Anyway I'd stay with the `TStringStream` / `TStringList` solution if possible.

Comment: `FileOpen()`/`FileWrite()` are provided by the Delphi RTL (they are in the `SysUtils` unit).  `AssignFile()`, `Rewrite()` and `Reset()` are old Pascal-style I/O functions, THOSE are the ones you should not be using anymore, Embarcadero does NOT encourage them.

Comment: @manlio: Thank you very much for you comment. Also the links are helpful to understand.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Thank you for your comment. I may be missing the point. Do you say, we should not use AssignFile(), Rewrite(), Reset() anymore?

Comment: @sevenOfNine: Yes, that is what I am saying.  They are legacy, deprecated, replaced with several other RTL alternatives.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Then, I may use TStreamWriter / TStringStream not using lower-level file access routines.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Of course you are right (and I also prefer other alternatives). Anyway the sentence about `FileOpen`/`FileWrite` comes directly from the last Embarcadero documentation (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.FileOpen)